# Message Date/Time tag in Lotus Notes

Tags: lotus-notes, blackberry

I've noticed that within Notes (8.5.2, basic client, standard client and iNotes) the date/time displayed on the eMail envelope AND the date/time on the message header is the same and appearently that time that Domino received the message.

When using BES, the message forwarded to the BlackBerry by Domino/BES has the RECEIVED date/time on the envelope and the SENT date/time displayed in the message.

In the basic/standard client with properties the sent time is viewable in one of the "Received" tags.

Having the sent time easily viewable is helpful, especially if your trying to trouble-shoot a problem.

Is this a configuration feature?
Is it selectable in the client or in Domino?

Thx

Comment: Please don't forget to mark your question as answered, or clarify if you need further assistance on it.

Answer (score 0):

PostedDate and DeliveredDate should remain the same as they are part of the mail message. Others will change depending on what they are used for.

Delivered Date should appear on the mail when you open it (right side on standard mail template). You can also view both in the document properties.